# RadGrid export to PowePoint

Tags: radgrid

is it possible to export the content of the Radgrid to Powerpoint? if so, can someone tell me the logic for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do this by generating Office HTML-compliant code. I haven't tried that, but I think you can get the Word output from RadGrid and stream it as a PPT file directly. Of course you will have to set the corresponding content-disposition and content-type headers. 
You can find some documentation on this format here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

Download the EXE file and extract it. The documentation is packed in CHM format.
Again, this is just an idea so don't take my words as 100% truth. Hope this helps.